# Date formats in VBA from Text String

Tags: excel, date, vba

I have an issue with date formats that I cannot get my head around.

I have 2 dates a reporting date which the user inputs Format is MM/DD/YYYY Showing as (11/15/2017) on the speadsheet. This is input from a Userform asking just for the Month and Date but uses the current year.

I then have a series of codes which validates the Data Line matches the ReportDate and produces information. To get Data date I need to look in a text string find a the word PPP and get the numbers proceeding the @ symbol.

I get the day and month value separately as only the day/month is visible in this string and appears like this `PPP@11/15`

Below is an extract of my code but it is not the full script.

```
Dim Year1 As Variant
Dim Month1 As Variant
Dim Day1 As Variant

If Not IsError(Mid(PODRng, InStr(1, PODRng, "PPP", vbTextCompare) + 4, 5)) Then                                                                                                        
Year1 = Format(Now(), "YYYY")
Month1 = Mid(PPPRng, InStr(1, PPPRng, "PPP", vbTextCompare) + 4, 2)
Day1 = Mid(PPPRng, InStr(1, PPPRng, "PPP", vbTextCompare) + 7, 2)
PPPTim = Day1 & "/" & Month1 & "/" & Year1
 'PPPTim.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"

    If PPPTim = ReportDate Then


        Cell.Offset(0, 49).Value = PPPTim ' 
    ElseIf InStr(1, PODRng, "PPP", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 49).Value = "Other Date"
    End If
```

End If

The data source is roughly 3k-5k lines and I have gone through the code and breaking when it gets to this code. I can confirm when checking the Locals both PPPTim and ReportDate are showing as 15/11/2017 but the match is coming through as False.

Hopefully someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

Dim podRNG As String, n1 As Integer, n2 As Integer, yourDate As Date

```
podRNG = "PPP@11/15"

n1 = InStr(podRNG, "@") + 1
n2 = InStr(podRNG, "/") + 1

PPPTim = CDate(Mid(podRNG, n1, n2 - n1 - 1) & "/" & Mid(podRNG, n2) & _
    "/" & Format(Now(), "YYYY"))
```

Returns (on my system):

> 2017-11-15

...since the data type is `Date`, the *date format will vary* based on your Regional Settings.

Comment: Perfect I have amended the code that inputs dates to have CDate and it seems to be working. Thank you.